# A conjectural permanent identity

Tags: nt.number-theory, determinants, combinatorial-identities, permanent, roots-of-unity

Let $n>1$ be an integer, and let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$th root of unity. By $(3.4)$ of [arXiv:2206.02589](http://arxiv.org/abs/2206.02589), $1$ and those $n+1-2s\ (s=1,\ldots,n-1)$ are all the eigenvalues of the matrix $M=[m_{jk}]_{1\le j,k\le n}$, where
$$m_{jk}=\begin{cases}(1+\zeta^{j-k})/(1-\zeta^{j-k})&\text{if}\ j\not=k,\\1&\text{if}\ j=k.\end{cases}\tag{1}$$
Thus we have
$$\det(M)=\prod_{s=1}^{n-1}(n+1-2s)=\begin{cases}(-1)^{n/2-1}\frac{((n-1)!!)^2}{n-1}&\text{if}\ 2\mid n,\\0&\text{if}\ 2\nmid n.\end{cases}.\tag{2}$$

What about the permanent of $M=[m_{jk}]_{1\le j,k\le n}$? I have the following conjecture based on my numerical computation.

**CONJECTURE.** If $n$ is a positive even number and $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity, then for the matrix $M=[m_{jk}]_{1\le j,k\le n}$ with $m_{jk}$ given by $(1)$, we have
$$\mathrm{per}(M)=((n-1)!!)^2.\tag{3}$$

**QUESTION.** Does the identity $(3)$ hold for any positive even number $n$?

Your comments are welcome!

**PS**: Let $n>1$ be odd. By [arXiv:2206.02589](http://arxiv.org/abs/2206.02589), we have
$$\det[m_{jk}]_{1\le j,k\le n-1}=(-1)^{(n+1)/2}\frac{((n-1)!!)^2}{n(n-1)}.\tag{4}$$
I also conjecture that
$$\mathrm{per}[m_{jk}]_{1\le j,k\le n-1}=\frac{((n-1)!!)^2}n.\tag{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

The two conjectures in the posting and postscript (concerning (3) and (5)) have been confirmed in the following paper via a novel permanent identity.

Yue-Feng She, Zhi-Wei Sun and Wei Xia, [A novel permanent identity with applications](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.12167), arXiv:2208.12167, 2022.